# Copy Icon into Startup Folder Using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, icons, copy, startup, startup-folder

I'd like to copy an icon into the computer's startup folder from vb.net code.

Comment: I assume you really want to create a shortcut to your application in the startup folder, not just copy a .ico file, which would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Startup Folder using the Environment.GetSpecialFolder function and then use File.Copy to copy out the file.

```
Public Sub CopyIconFromStartup(iconName as String, target As String) 
  Dim path as String = Environment.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolder.Startup)
  path = IO.Path.Combine(path, iconName)
  File.Copy(path, target)
End Sub
```